# Extracting data from indexPathsForSelectedRows() - SWIFT

Tags: uitableview, swift

I'm trying to extract all data from selected rows in my table. I use the following code to print the indexPaths. But what do I have to do to print out the text from the selected rows?

```
     let indexPaths:NSArray = tableView.indexPathsForSelectedRows()!


            `for var i = 0; i < indexPaths.count; ++i {

            var thisPath:NSIndexPath = indexPaths.objectAtIndex(i) as NSIndexPath

            println("row = \(thisPath.row) and section = \(thisPath.section)")
       }
```

Prints to console the selected rows

```
row = 1 and section = 0
row = 3 and section = 0
```

`row = 6 and section = 0`

Comment: Fetch the data from your data model identically to who you fetch it in cellForRowAtIndexPath?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method of `UITableView` to obtain a cell by index path:

```
if let indexPaths = tableView.indexPathsForSelectedRows() {
    for var i = 0; i < indexPaths.count; ++i {

        var thisPath = indexPaths[i] as NSIndexPath
        var cell = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(thisPath)
        if let cell = cell {
            // Do something with the cell
            // If it's a custom cell, downcast to the proper type
        }
    }
}
```

Note that `indexPathsForSelectedRows` returns an optional (nil when no row is selected), so it's better to protect it with an optional binding to prevent runtime exceptions.

Comment: Antonio, when I use your code, I'm getting an error where "var thisPath" is declared. On that line I'm getting a '[AnyObject]' does not have a member named 'objectAtIndex.

Comment: My mistake - code fixed, replaced `objectAtIndex ` with subscript. If you still get the error about `thisPath`, it means you have a variable with the same name in the method (or class property) - just rename it to something else, like `currentPath`

Comment: Use `var thisPath = (indexPaths! as [NSIndexPath])[i]`

Comment: `indexPaths` can be nil (in the OP code), so using the forced unwrapping can generate a runtime error