# Selecting multiple items in a UITableView

Tags: ios, uitableview, rows

I have a class called `ItemClass` and a `UITableView` with the class items displayed. With `indexPathsForSelectedRows`, I want the possibility of making multiple selections.

In my `pressedButton` action, I created a `for` loop that takes every selected `ItemClass` object and puts them in an array. For some reason, I can't get anything to work.

Is it because of the SelectedRows instead of Row? Does anyone have any suggestions?

```
class Item: NSObject {
    var title: String
    var binfo: String

    init(title: String, binfo: String) {
        self.title = title
        self.binfo = binfo
    }
}   

@IBAction func pressButton(sender: UIButton) {
    if let selectedItems = tableView.indexPathsForSelectedRows {

        var ItemsArray: [ItemClass] = []

        for indexPath in selectedItems {
            //How do I get each Item from the selectedItems in the ItemsArray???

        }
        sharedContentManager.memoryArray = ItemsArray
    }
}
```

Comment: I guess you must create array where UITableView Delegates implemented.may be this [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27237326/swift-save-checkmarks-selected-in-tableview] helps you.

Comment: Maybe this post could help you? [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27089336/extracting-data-from-indexpathsforselectedrows-swift](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27089336/extracting-data-from-indexpathsforselectedrows-swift) Instead of getting a reference to the cell, just use the indexPath.row property to get the item out of your source array.